# Flask SQLAlchemy - querying a view with non-default named schema. What's the best approach?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a view (`view1`) in a postgres database (`dbtable`) that I want to be able to interact with using Flask-SQLAlchemy.

I've tried a couple of ways and run into errors. I'm not sure if the fact that the table/view have a non-default named schema (`db_schema`) is causing the problem

What's the best way of doing this?

---

With the following setup:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class Config:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgres://postgres:example@IP_ADDRESS:5432/dbtable"
    SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {"db_key": SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI},
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
```

I tried to query using:

```py
str_query = """
        SELECT *
            FROM "view1"
            WHERE "date" > '{}'""".format(
    cutoff_date
)
resultproxy = db.engine.execute(str_query)
```

and got this error:

```sh
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "view1" does not exist
LINE 3:                 FROM "view1"
                             ^

[SQL: 
            SELECT *
                FROM "view1"
                WHERE "date" > '2020-11-01']
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

So, I tried adding the view as an object, like this:

---

EDIT:

now specified Table definition and overridden `id` to be a primary key

Still can't query the view though.

```py
class Table1(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = "db_key"
    __tablename__ = "table1"

    __table_args__ = {"autoload": True, "autoload_with": db.engine, "schema": "db_schema"}
        
class View1(db.Model):
    #__bind_key__ = "db_key"
    #__tablename__ = "view1"
    
    #__table_args__ = {"autoload": True, "autoload_with": db.engine, "schema": "db_schema"}
    __table__ = Table('view1', db.Model.metadata,
             Column("id", String, primary_key=True), 
              Column("date", DateTime), 
              extend_existing=True,
                 info={'bind_key': 'db_key', "schema": "db_schema"})
    
    def get_all(self):
        items = self.query.all()
        return items
```

When I try to query

```py
view1 = View1()
items = view1.get_all()
```

I get:

```sh
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: Does your view have a primary key, or could one or more of its columns be considered a primary key?  See [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html?highlight=views#reflecting-views).

Comment: I don't think my database view can have primary key? I've tried specifying the view as a Table and overridden a column to make a primary key. I still can't query against it. Have edited question

Comment: Can you share the DDL for the original table and view? It's difficult to know exactly what we're working with here.

Comment: This approach actually works when I put it into my project, just failed on the toy example (not sure why). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction